# Edge highlight length of selected vertex

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I have made the selection highlight somehow extremely shot, but only for single object. Every other object in scene has normal edge highlights for selected vertex. I might've accidently moved some kind of bar, but I have no idea which one. Below are examples of highlights of problematic object and newly created cube within same project
[image: shortened, barely visible highlight]

[image]

Comment: have u tried pressing `a` to select all vertices and pressing `m` > *merge by distance*

Comment: A bit late on that, since answer was already given, but yes, it was the first thing I tried and even duplication of vertices would've been the case, highlights were not displayed at all most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've enabled the 'On Cage' option in Subdivision Modifier.
This shows the mesh with more vertices, which makes the gradient shorter.

[image]

Comment: oh, I guess then the highlight shows for subdivides mesh if "on cage" is on. That is why it was way so short. Thanks, new to blender and would no have figured it on my own!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Welcome to blender btw :)